# How to make body divided into 3 equal part using container?

Tags: flutter, containers

I want to make my screen into 3 equal part using **container class** in flutter.  How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html), it `constraints` that can be used to get body height,maxWidth, also it provides  more than this. Also, you can try media query.

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
        body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: constraints.maxHeight / 3,
            width: constraints.maxWidth,
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
          Container(
            height:size.height/3,
            width: size.width/3,
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

You can remove `Column` it's just an example. Using `LayoutBuilder` provide parents' constraints.

Comment: Can you show using mediaquery ?

Comment: Sure, but avoid using query too much, it may affect the performance.

Comment: does it solve your issue?

Comment: Yeasin bhai can you suggest me some best tutorial for learning flutter . Because i'm completely new to this

Comment: I think you will on youtube, but I prefer reading official doc from flutter.dev and pub.dev

Comment: Any  channel name? Also can you upvote to my question ?

Comment: You can find by little search, there is also `flutter` official channel and my fav show is `widget of the week`. And sorry about vote, please read [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `Flexible` widget

Let's say you want the three equal parts to be stacked vertically

```
return Column(
  children: [
    Flexible(child: Container()),
    Flexible(child: Container()),
    Flexible(child: Container()),
  ]
);
```

You can also specify a flex component to signify the relationship between the widgets' sizes

```
return Column(
  children: [
    Flexible(child: Container(), flex:1),
    Flexible(child: Container(), flex:2),
  ]
);
```

which will make the second widget take 2/3 of the available space

Comment: i want to divided it by horizontal and the format should be like this 
body: Container(
          child:

Comment: ok, so `body: Container(child: Column(children: [...]))` although I don't see why you need the container there

Comment: if you want it horizontal use a Row